# Конфликт скриптов, галерея

Tags: javascript

Менюшки плавно скролились по якорям лендинга. Но после того как я подключила новую галерею, скролинг на якорь к этой галереи не работает (остальные скролятся нормально).

Код запуска:

```js
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function () {
 /* Video Lightbox */
 if (!!$.prototype.simpleLightboxVideo) {
  $('.video').simpleLightboxVideo();
 }

 /*ScrollUp*/
 if (!!$.prototype.scrollUp) {
  $.scrollUp();
 }

 /*Logo ScrollUp*/
 $('#name').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        },1000);
        return false;
    });

 /*Responsive Navigation*/
 $("#nav-mobile").html($("#nav-main").html());
 $("#nav-trigger span").on("click",function() {
  if ($("nav#nav-mobile ul").hasClass("expanded")) {
   $("nav#nav-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
   $(this).removeClass("open");
  } else {
   $("nav#nav-mobile ul").addClass("expanded").slideDown(250);
   $(this).addClass("open");
  }
 });

 $("#nav-mobile").html($("#nav-main").html());
 $("#nav-mobile ul a").on("click",function() {
  if ($("nav#nav-mobile ul").hasClass("expanded")) {
   $("nav#nav-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
   $("#nav-trigger span").removeClass("open");
  }
 });

 /* Sticky Navigation */
 if (!!$.prototype.stickyNavbar) {
  $('#header').stickyNavbar();
 }

 $('#content').waypoint(function (direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
   $('#header').addClass('nav-solid fadeInDown');
  }
  else {
   $('#header').removeClass('nav-solid fadeInDown');
  }
 });

});


/* Preloader and animations */
$(window).load(function () { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
 $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
 $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
 $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow-y': 'visible'});

 /* WOW Elements */
 if (typeof WOW == 'function') {
  new WOW().init();
 }

 /* Parallax Effects */
 if (!!$.prototype.enllax) {
  $(window).enllax();
 }

});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   jQuery("#gallery").unitegallery({
    gallery_theme: "tilesgrid",
    tile_width: 300,
    tile_height: 300,
    grid_num_rows:2,
   });

  });
```